# Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 39

Tags: python

This exercise is mostly sinking in although I am wondering about Zed's use of "state" and "abbrev". "state" (assuming this isn't a typo), is the singular version of "states" but does python understand it as this? There is no dictionary for "state", only "states". Also "abbrev" is not mentioned anywhere until the second bit of code below so how does python know what "abbrev" is? Python doesn't know we are abbreviating state names, only that we have associated the two capital letters with the state names.

```
# create a mapping of state to abbreviation

states = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
}

# print every state abbreviation

print '-' * 25
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (state, abbrev)
```

Comment: thanks soon, I could not get a post preview so could not see how bad that code would look once posted.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't know or infer anything from your variable names. All it knows is that you have a dictionary of arbitrary strings which happen to map to other arbitrary strings.

The loop just says "pull out the key-value pairs in the dictionary" and store the keys in the first variable, and the values in the second variable.

You can change the program as follows and see it still work.

```
# create a mapping of state to abbreviation

monkeys = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
}

# print every state abbreviation

print '-' * 25
for cat, dog in monkeys.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (cat, dog)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't look at the "morphological" part of the code. It doesn't convert "meaning" (plural / singular)

You could as well write the second part as:

```
for x, y in states.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (x, y)
```

What Python is looking for are groups of (x, y) .. where x is the first item in the dictionary (key), and y is the second item in the dictionary (value).

What that for loop does is go over pairs of (x, y) and each pair is considered an "item" like a single item in a vector `states[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

states.items() is return a key, value pair of data. state and abbrev are the variable names in the for statement. You could name state and abbrev to anything else if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

**`states`** dictionary has:

- **state_name** (which is the key) # Oregon, Florida, California, New York, Michigan
- **state_two_letter_code** (which is the value) # OR, FL, CA, NY, MI

So in that **`for`** loop:

- **state, abbrev** should be understood as **state_name**, **state_two_letter_code**

And every time it loops:

- **state**, **abbrev** will be assigned those values from the dictionary for every item

You could put any names you want. Since **`states.items()`** returns a **`(key, value)`** tuple which will be assigned to the variable names you put in there:

```
for key, value in states.items():
    print "State name: {}".format(key)
    print "State Two Letter Code: {}".format(value)
```

This is a good example:

```
def splitEmail(email):
    return email.split('@') # this returns: ['someone', 'gmail.com']

# 'someone' is assigned to 'account' and 'gmail.com' is assigned to domain
account, domain = splitEmail('someone@gmail.com') 

print account
print domain
```

Output:

```
someone
gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

`states.items()` return a list of tuples containing a key and value for the entries in the dictionary. The `for` simply "unpack" each tuple in different variables. A tuple representation in python look like this `(1, 2)`.

This interactive ipython session I made might help you understand the logic.

```
In [2]: states.items()
Out[2]: 
[('California', 'CA'),
 ('Michigan', 'MI'),
 ('New York', 'NY'),
 ('Florida', 'FL'),
 ('Oregon', 'OR')]

In [3]: states.items()[0]
Out[3]: ('California', 'CA')

In [4]: a, b = states.items()[0]    
In [5]: print a, b
California CA

In [6]: for a, b in [(1, 1), (2, 2)]:
   ...:     print a, b
   ...:     
1 1
2 2
```